# date: get current 15 minute interval

Tags: command-line, date

Is there any way I can get the current 15 minute interval using the date command or similar ?

e.g. something like date `%Y.%m.%d %H:%M`  will give me `2011.02.22 10:19` , I need something that yields `2011.02.22 10:15` in the time span from `10:15` to `10:29`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can get the current unix timestamp with `date "+%s"`, find the current quarter-hour with some simple math (my example is in `bash`) and print it back with a better format with `date` :

```
curdate=`date "+%s"`
curquarter=$(($curdate - ($curdate % (15 * 60))))
date -d"@$curquarter"
```

The `@` syntax to set the current date and time from a timestamp is a GNU extention to date, if it don't works on your OS, you can do the same like this (don't forget to specify UTC, otherwise, it won't work) :

```
date -d"1970-01-01 $curquarter seconds UTC"
```

Answer (score 5):

The following methods make it unnecessary to call `date` twice.
A system call's overhead can make a "simple" command 100 times slower than bash doing the same thing in its own local environment.

**UPDATE** Just a quick mention about my above comment: "100 times slower". It can now read "**500** times slower"... I recently fell (no, walked blindly) into this very issue. here is the link: [Fast way to build a test file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8273/fast-way-to-build-a-test-file-with-every-second-listed-in-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss-for)

```
eval $(date +Y=%Y\;m=%m\;d=%d\;H=%H\;M=%M)
[[ "$M" < "15" ]] && M=00 # cater for octal clash
M=$(((M/15)*15))
((M==0)) && M=00 # the math returns 0, so make it 00  
echo $Y.$m.$d $H:$M
```

or

```
eval $(date +Y=%Y\;m=%m\;d=%d\;H=%H\;M=%M)
if   [[ "$M" < "15" ]] ; then M=00
elif [[ "$M" < "30" ]] ; then M=15
elif [[ "$M" < "45" ]] ; then M=30
else M=45
fi
echo $Y.$m.$d $H:$M
```

Both versions will return only

```
2011.02.23 01:00
2011.02.23 01:15
2011.02.23 01:30
2011.02.23 01:45
```

---

Here is the first one with a TEST loop for all 60 values {00..59}

```
for X in {00..59} ;                         ###### TEST
do                                          ###### TEST 
  eval $(date +Y=%Y\;m=%m\;d=%d\;H=%H\;M=%M)
  M=$X                                      ###### TEST 
  [[ "$M" < "15" ]] && M=00 # cater for octal clash
  M=$(((M/15)*15))
  ((M==0)) && M=00 # the math returns 0, so make it 00  
  echo $Y.$m.$d $H:$M 
done                                        ###### TEST
```

Comment: Just for clarification — by "system call", you mean "fork/exec/wait, like the system() call", not _system call_ in general. (I mention this because making system calls also has an overhead within a program, because of the user/kernel switch. That's not the particular issue here.)

Comment: mattdm... Thanks.. I'm working from only 6 months Linux experience, so I've quite likely used the wrong phrase, but I keep reading about the overheads incurred by unnecessary calls, and in my own experience of testing my own scripts, I've seen many examples where calling `printf` or `sed` and also that "unnecessary" `cat` vs  <file does make a dramatic actual run-time difference. when looping, as in my "500 times slower" example.. So it seems that using the shell wherever possible, and allowing a program such as `date` to batch process is what I mean.. eg. Gilles' Left-Pad-0 example, vs printf

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to work on dates in the shell. First call `date` to get the components, and fill the positional parameters (`$1`, `$2`, etc) with the components (note that this is one of these rare cases where you do want to use `$(…)` outside of double quotes, to break the string into words). Then perform arithmetics, tests, or whatever you need to do on the components. Finally assemble the components.

The arithmetic part can be a little tricky because shells treat `0` as an octal prefix; for example here `$(($5/15))` would fail at 8 or 9 minutes past the hour. Since there's at most one leading `0`, `${5#0}` is safe for arithmetic. Adding 100 and subsequently stripping the `1` is a way to get a fixed number of digits in the output.

```
set $(date "+%Y %m %d %H %M")
m=$((100+15*(${5#0}/15)))
last_quarter_hour="$1.$2.$3 $4:${m#1}"
```

Comment: "The tricks of the trade" ...a good one. :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it doesn't matter anymore but you could try my very own [dateutils](http://hroptatyr.github.com/dateutils).  Rounding (down) to minutes is done with `dround` and a negative argument:

```
dround now /-15m
=>
  2012-07-11T13:00:00
```

Or to adhere to your format:

```
dround now /-15m -f '%Y.%m.%d %H:%M'
=>
  2012.07.11 13:00
```

Comment: is that actually how your utils work anymore? using -15m I get the input rewound to the nearest 15 minutes past an hour: `dateutils.dround '2018-11-12 13:55' -15m` produces `2018-11-12T13:15:00` not `2018-11-12T13:45:00`.

Comment: @JackDouglas The tools have evolved, what you want is now: `/-15m`, i.e. round down to the next multiple of 15 minutes in the hour.  This feature got the more cumbersome syntax because it accepts less values, /-13m isn't possible for instance because 13 is not a divisor of 60 (minutes in the hour)

Comment: nice, I get what I need now with `dateutils.dround '2018-11-12 12:52:31' /450s /-15m`, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Some shells are able to do the work without calling an external `date` command:

[ksh](/questions/tagged/ksh)   `a=$(printf '%(%s)T\n'); printf '%(%Y.%m.%d %H:%M)T\n' "#$((a-a%(15*60)))"`
   [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) `a=$(printf '%(%s)T\n'); printf '%(%Y.%m.%d %H:%M)T\n' "$((a-a%(15*60)))"`
   [zsh](/questions/tagged/zsh) `zmodload zsh/datetime; a=$EPOCHSECONDS; strftime '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M' $((a-a%(15*60)))`

The three above provide local (not UTC) time. Use a leading TZ=UTC0 if needed.

The ksh and bash syntax is almost identical (except for the required `#` in ksh). The zsh require to load a module (included with the zsh distribution).

It is also possible to do it with (GNU) awk:

[gawk](/questions/tagged/gawk) `awk 'BEGIN{t=systime();print strftime("%Y.%m.%d %H:%M",t-t%(15*60),1)}'`

This provide an UTC result (change the last `1` to `0`) if local is needed.
But loading an external awk or an external zsh module might be as slow as calling date itself:

[gnu-date](/questions/tagged/gnu-date) `a=$(date +%s); date -ud "@$((a-a%(15*60)))" +'%Y.%m.%d %H:%M'`

A small executable like `busybox` could provide similar results:

[busybox-date](/questions/tagged/busybox-date) `a=$(busybox date +%s);busybox date -ud "@$((a-a%(15*60)))" +'%Y.%m.%d %H:%M'`

Note that the leading busybox word may be omitted if busybox is linked to those names in a directory of the PATH.

Both `date` and `busybox date` above will print UTC times. Remove the `-u` option for local times.

---

If your OS has a more limited version of date (and that is what you must use) then try:

```
a=$(date +%s); a=$(( a-a%(15*60) ))
date -d"1970-01-01 $a seconds UTC" +'%Y.%m.%d %H:%M'
```

Or, if in FreeBSD, try:

```
a=$(date +%s); a=$(( a-a%(15*60) ))
date -r "$a" +'%Y.%m.%d %H:%M'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can live with calling date two times, this one works in bash on Solaris:

```
date +"%Y.%m.%d %H:$(( $(date +'%M') / 15 * 15 ))"
```

Edited on behalf of the comment to:

```
date +"%Y.%m.%d %H:$(( $(date +'%M') / 15 * 15 ))" | sed 's/:0$/:00/'
```

Comment: In the first qurarter of the hour, this will produce a minutes output with only a single 0 instead of 00

Comment: Corrected, it is a simple sed after the original command.

Comment: One more bug: it doesn't work between H:08 and H:10. See [my answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7833/date-get-current-15-minute-interval/7865#7865) for why and a fix.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a little late, but I just needed similar for Awk:

`show_time.awk`

```awk
function round(t, i) {
    return int(t/i + .5)*i
}
BEGIN {
    print strftime("%F %H:%M", round(systime(), 15*60))
}
```

This can be called in bash:

```shellsession
$ awk -f show_time.awk
```

Answer (score -1):

Am not sure about your exact requirement. However, if you want to generate the time after 15 min, then you can use something like `date  -d '+15 min'`. Output is shown below:

```
$ date; date  -d '+15 min'
Tue Feb 22 18:12:39 IST 2011
Tue Feb 22 18:27:39 IST 2011
```

Comment: You misunderstood the question. The point is to round the date (down) to a multiple of 15 minutes.