# 15 min interval rounded parameter as starting and ending time in a specified format

Tags: linux, shell-script, date

I wanted to pass parameters in a  shell script which calls a java program...

For example the current time is 2011:02:23 01:05 then I need to floor to nearest whole time like 1:00 (starttime parameter to java program) if its 1:05 and 1:15 (end time parameter to java program)
the below timestamps I wanted to dynamically pass to a java program based on current time.

Example param(15min interval) to pass to java program via shell script.

> java  2011:02:23 01:00 (start time)  2011.02.23 01:15 (end time)
>   java  2011.02.23 01:15 (starttime)   2011.02.23 01:30 (end time)

Can I ? or is there any way to generate the date with time in above specified format in unix ?

Note : This [date: get current 15 minute interval](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7833/date-get-current-15-minute-interval) doesnt serve my purpose.

Comment: "ceil" (ceiling) rounding would take 1:05 to something *higher*, not something *lower* such as 1:00. Can you spell out the translation in more detail? What are the possible inputs and resulting outputs?

Comment: @jeff-schaller : updated. I need 2011:02:23 01:00(starttime param to java) if current time is 2011:02:23 01:08 . end time should look like 2011:02:23 01:15

Comment: @JeffSchaller any pointers you can help with ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the number of minutes multiple of 15 lower than current minutes (or minutes given in the first parameter) with:

```
a=$(date date -d "2011-02-23 01:05" +%-m)        # need only minutes.
a=${1:-"$a"}                   # or use the value from the first parameter.
a=${a#0}                       # remove one optional leading zero to
                               # avoid issues with 08 and 09.
b=$((a-a%15))                  # Round down to a 15 minutes multiple.
c=$((b+15))                    # end time

echo "$b $c"
```

If you need a full date string use:

```
$ printf 'java %s%02d\n' "$(date -d "2011-02-23 01:05" +"%Y:%m:%d %H:")" "$b"
java 2011:02:23 01:00
```

Or, in bash:

```
$ printf -v a '%(%s)T\n' -1
$ printf '%(java %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S)T\n' "$(( a - a % (60*15) ))"
java 2018-08-30 22:45:00
```

Comment: Hi Isaac not working as expected in the post

Comment: @RamPrasadG Maybe a description of which part doesn't work could be useful. :-(

Comment: Thanks for the solution! some how its not working for me.

Comment: @RamPrasadG I am sorry to hear that. Good luck.